# getting error on form onSubmit because of wrong type in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the below function and when I pass the function into another component I need to define the type of `updateChannelInfo` but my type is showing wrong,

```
const updateChannelInfo = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateTitle(channelTitle);
    selectedGame && updateChannelGame(selectedGame);
  };
```

I am getting error on onSubmit

```
interface EditChannelInfo {
  updateChannelInfo: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
}

const EditChannelInfoCollapse = (props: EditChannelInfo): ReactElement => {
 <form onSubmit={updateChannelInfo}>
 ...
 </form>

}
```

Error:

```
(property) DOMAttributes<HTMLFormElement>.onSubmit?: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> | undefined
Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
  Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1384, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
interface EditChannelInfo {
  updateChannelInfo: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
}
```

should be

```
interface EditChannelInfo {
  updateChannelInfo: (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative answer to the existing one from Ioannis, you can skip having to declare the shape of the function and opt to use the handler type instead:

```
interface EditChannelInfo {
  updateChannelInfo: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>;
}
```